# Jenkins Pipeline - Enabling Cloudfoundry deployment

Tags: jenkins, cloud-foundry, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

Installed Blue Ocean from the docker image `docker pull jenkinsci/blueocean`. I wanted to include a Cloud Foundry Deployment step (`sh cf push`) in my pipeline and stuck with the error:

```
script.sh: line 1: cf: not found
```

I knew what's happening - as there is no compatible CF CLI plug-in the script command CF is not working. And I tried different things:

In my `Jenkinsfile`, I Tried using the the Cloud foundry plug-in (CloudFoundryPushPublisher) which is supported in non-pipeline build. And that didn't help.

```
step([$class: 'com.hpe.cloudfoundryjenkins.CloudFoundryPushPublisher',
        target: 'https://api.ng.bluemix.net',
        organization: 'xxxx',
        cloudSpace: 'xxxxx',
        credentialsId: 'xxxxxx',
        selfSigned: true,
        resetIfExists: true]);
```

That failed with `Invalid Argument exception`.

My question is, I heard Cloudbees has a commercial version that supports CF CLI, but that ability is missing from Blue ocean. So how should I be able to push the deployments to cloud foundry using Pipeline job?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you already fixed the issue, but I just installed 'cf cli' on jenkins machine by manual and use 'cf push' as shell script like;

```
sh 'cf login -u xxx - p xxx -s space -o org'
sh 'cf push appname ...'
```

Comment: When I set-up BlueOcean and CF-CLI on my Mac there are no issues. CF commands from the JenkinsFile execute with no problem. However, when want to run BlueOcean on a docker instance where the CF plugin is not available on the same container the execution fails. For now, I have given up on docker image for blue ocean.